# When I enable SSL on apache2 ubuntu server both http and https does not work

Tags: ssl, apache2, ubuntu-server

I am trying to enable SSL for my webserver. However, when I enable ssl, http stops working and https does not start working. I have followed the following guide:

https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-create-a-ssl-certificate-on-apache-for-ubuntu-14-04

There is no firewall activated on the server.
This is the default-ssl.conf file:

```
<IfModule mod_ssl.c>
        <VirtualHost _default_:443>
                ServerAdmin admin@MyWebSit.com
                ServerName MyWebSite.com
                ServerAlias www.MyWebSite.com

                DocumentRoot /var/www/html

                # Available loglevels: trace8, ..., trace1, debug, info, notice, warn,
                # error, crit, alert, emerg.
                # It is also possible to configure the loglevel for particular
                # modules, e.g.
                #LogLevel info ssl:warn

                ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
                CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

                # For most configuration files from conf-available/, which are
                # enabled or disabled at a global level, it is possible to
                # include a line for only one particular virtual host. For example the
                # following line enables the CGI configuration for this host only
                # after it has been globally disabled with "a2disconf".
                #Include conf-available/serve-cgi-bin.conf

                #   SSL Engine Switch:
                #   Enable/Disable SSL for this virtual host.
                SSLEngine on

                #   A self-signed (snakeoil) certificate can be created by installing
                #   the ssl-cert package. See
                #   /usr/share/doc/apache2/README.Debian.gz for more info.
                #   If both key and certificate are stored in the same file, only the
                #   SSLCertificateFile directive is needed.
                SSLCertificateFile      /etc/apache2/ssl/MyWebSite_com.crt
                SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/apache2/ssl/MyWebSite_com.key

                #   Server Certificate Chain:
                #   Point SSLCertificateChainFile at a file containing the
                #   concatenation of PEM encoded CA certificates which form the
                #   certificate chain for the server certificate. Alternatively
                #   the referenced file can be the same as SSLCertificateFile
                #   when the CA certificates are directly appended to the server
                #   certificate for convinience.
                #SSLCertificateChainFile /etc/apache2/ssl.crt/server-ca.crt

                #   Certificate Authority (CA):
                #   Set the CA certificate verification path where to find CA
                #   certificates for client authentication or alternatively one
                #   huge file containing all of them (file must be PEM encoded)
                #   Note: Inside SSLCACertificatePath you need hash symlinks
                #                to point to the certificate files. Use the provided
                #                Makefile to update the hash symlinks after changes.
                #SSLCACertificatePath /etc/ssl/certs/
                #SSLCACertificateFile /etc/apache2/ssl.crt/ca-bundle.crt

                #   Certificate Revocation Lists (CRL):
                #   Set the CA revocation path where to find CA CRLs for client
                #   authentication or alternatively one huge file containing all
                #   of them (file must be PEM encoded)
                #   Note: Inside SSLCARevocationPath you need hash symlinks
                #                to point to the certificate files. Use the provided
                #                Makefile to update the hash symlinks after changes.
                #SSLCARevocationPath /etc/apache2/ssl.crl/
                #SSLCARevocationFile /etc/apache2/ssl.crl/ca-bundle.crl

                #   Client Authentication (Type):
                #   Client certificate verification type and depth.  Types are
                #   none, optional, require and optional_no_ca.  Depth is a
                #   number which specifies how deeply to verify the certificate
                #   issuer chain before deciding the certificate is not valid.
                #SSLVerifyClient require
                #SSLVerifyDepth  10

                #   SSL Engine Options:
                #   Set various options for the SSL engine.
                #   o FakeBasicAuth:
                #        Translate the client X.509 into a Basic Authorisation.  This means that
                #        the standard Auth/DBMAuth methods can be used for access control.  The
                #        user name is the `one line' version of the client's X.509 certificate.
                #        Note that no password is obtained from the user. Every entry in the user
                #        file needs this password: `xxj31ZMTZzkVA'.
                #   o ExportCertData:
                #        This exports two additional environment variables: SSL_CLIENT_CERT and
                #        SSL_SERVER_CERT. These contain the PEM-encoded certificates of the
                #        server (always existing) and the client (only existing when client
                #        authentication is used). This can be used to import the certificates
                #        into CGI scripts.
                #   o StdEnvVars:
                #        This exports the standard SSL/TLS related `SSL_*' environment variables.
                #        Per default this exportation is switched off for performance reasons,
                #        because the extraction step is an expensive operation and is usually
                #        useless for serving static content. So one usually enables the
                #        exportation for CGI and SSI requests only.
                #   o OptRenegotiate:
                #        This enables optimized SSL connection renegotiation handling when SSL
                #        directives are used in per-directory context.
                #SSLOptions +FakeBasicAuth +ExportCertData +StrictRequire
                <FilesMatch "\.(cgi|shtml|phtml|php)$">
                                SSLOptions +StdEnvVars
                </FilesMatch>
                <Directory /usr/lib/cgi-bin>
                                SSLOptions +StdEnvVars
                </Directory>

                #   SSL Protocol Adjustments:
                #   The safe and default but still SSL/TLS standard compliant shutdown
                #   approach is that mod_ssl sends the close notify alert but doesn't wait for
                #   the close notify alert from client. When you need a different shutdown
                #   approach you can use one of the following variables:
                #   o ssl-unclean-shutdown:
                #        This forces an unclean shutdown when the connection is closed, i.e. no
                #        SSL close notify alert is send or allowed to received.  This violates
                #        the SSL/TLS standard but is needed for some brain-dead browsers. Use
                #        this when you receive I/O errors because of the standard approach where
                #        mod_ssl sends the close notify alert.
                #   o ssl-accurate-shutdown:
                #        This forces an accurate shutdown when the connection is closed, i.e. a
                #        SSL close notify alert is send and mod_ssl waits for the close notify
                #        alert of the client. This is 100% SSL/TLS standard compliant, but in
                #        practice often causes hanging connections with brain-dead browsers. Use
                #        this only for browsers where you know that their SSL implementation
                #        works correctly.
                #   Notice: Most problems of broken clients are also related to the HTTP
                #   keep-alive facility, so you usually additionally want to disable
                #   keep-alive for those clients, too. Use variable "nokeepalive" for this.
                #   Similarly, one has to force some clients to use HTTP/1.0 to workaround
                #   their broken HTTP/1.1 implementation. Use variables "downgrade-1.0" and
                #   "force-response-1.0" for this.
                # BrowserMatch "MSIE [2-6]" \
                #               nokeepalive ssl-unclean-shutdown \
                #               downgrade-1.0 force-response-1.0

        </VirtualHost>
</IfModule>

# vim: syntax=apache ts=4 sw=4 sts=4 sr noet
```

apache -S gives me:

> AH00111: Config variable ${APACHE_RUN_DIR} is not defined
>   apache2: Syntax error on line 80 of /etc/apache2/apache2.conf: DefaultRuntimeDir must be a valid directory, absolute or relative to ServerRoot

and apachectl -S gives me:

> AH00558: apache2: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using 192.168.178.24. Set the 'ServerName' directive globally to suppress this message
>   VirtualHost configuration:
>   *:80 192.168.178.24 (/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default.conf:1)
>   *:443 MyWebSite.com (/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/default-ssl.conf:2)
>   ServerRoot: "/etc/apache2"
>   Main DocumentRoot: "/var/www/html"
>   Main ErrorLog: "/var/log/apache2/error.log"
>   Mutex watchdog-callback: using_defaults
>   Mutex ssl-stapling-refresh: using_defaults
>   Mutex ssl-stapling: using_defaults
>   Mutex ssl-cache: using_defaults
>   Mutex default: dir="/var/run/apache2/" mechanism=default
>   Mutex mpm-accept: using_defaults
>   PidFile: "/var/run/apache2/apache2.pid"
>   Define: DUMP_VHOSTS
>   Define: DUMP_RUN_CFG
>   User: name="www-data" id=33
>   Group: name="www-data" id=33

disabling ssl immediately gets http back up. (after a restart of Apache)

Unfortunately, I no longer know what I can try to do.
any assistance here would be greatly appreciated!

Thank you in advance!

EDIT:
As it is clear the information I've provided does not fully explain my issue, I am adding additional details here:

```
sudo service apache2 restart
```

Gives the following result:

> Warning: The unit file, source configuration file or drop-ins of
>   apache2.service changed on disk. Run 'systemctl daemon-reload' to
>   reload units. Job for apache2.service failed because the control
>   process exited with error code. See "systemctl status apache2.service"
>   and "journalctl -xe" for details

```
systemctl daemon-reload
```

Runs successfully, but I still get the Job failed response when running the restart command again. Below is the response for "systemctl status apache2.service"

```
● apache2.service - The Apache HTTP Server
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/apache2.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
  Drop-In: /lib/systemd/system/apache2.service.d
           └─apache2-systemd.conf
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Mon 2019-12-02 11:08:57 CET; 3h 28min ago
  Process: 4557 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/apachectl start (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
 Main PID: 1413 (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)

Dec 02 11:08:57 ubuntu systemd[1]: Starting The Apache HTTP Server...
Dec 02 11:08:57 ubuntu apachectl[4557]: AH00558: apache2: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using 192.168.178.24. Set the 'ServerNa
Dec 02 11:08:57 ubuntu apachectl[4557]: Action 'start' failed.
Dec 02 11:08:57 ubuntu apachectl[4557]: The Apache error log may have more information.
Dec 02 11:08:57 ubuntu systemd[1]: apache2.service: Control process exited, code=exited status=1
Dec 02 11:08:57 ubuntu systemd[1]: apache2.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Dec 02 11:08:57 ubuntu systemd[1]: Failed to start The Apache HTTP Server.
```

And below is the result for journalctl -xe

```
--
-- Unit motd-news.service has begun starting up.
Dec 02 13:56:00 ubuntu 50-motd-news[5122]:  * Overheard at KubeCon: "microk8s.status just blew my mind".
Dec 02 13:56:00 ubuntu 50-motd-news[5122]:      https://microk8s.io/docs/commands#microk8s.status
Dec 02 13:56:00 ubuntu systemd[1]: Started Message of the Day.
-- Subject: Unit motd-news.service has finished start-up
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://www.ubuntu.com/support
--
-- Unit motd-news.service has finished starting up.
--
-- The start-up result is RESULT.
Dec 02 14:09:02 ubuntu CRON[5169]: pam_unix(cron:session): session opened for user root by (uid=0)
Dec 02 14:09:02 ubuntu CRON[5170]: (root) CMD (  [ -x /usr/lib/php/sessionclean ] && if [ ! -d /run/systemd/system ]; then /usr/lib/php/sessionclean; fi)
Dec 02 14:09:02 ubuntu CRON[5169]: pam_unix(cron:session): session closed for user root
Dec 02 14:09:44 ubuntu systemd[1]: Starting Clean php session files...
-- Subject: Unit phpsessionclean.service has begun start-up
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://www.ubuntu.com/support
--
-- Unit phpsessionclean.service has begun starting up.
Dec 02 14:09:44 ubuntu sessionclean[5171]: PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'mysqli' (tried: /usr/lib/php/20170718/mysqli (/usr/lib/php/2017071
Dec 02 14:09:44 ubuntu systemd[1]: Started Clean php session files.
-- Subject: Unit phpsessionclean.service has finished start-up
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://www.ubuntu.com/support
--
-- Unit phpsessionclean.service has finished starting up.
--
-- The start-up result is RESULT.
Dec 02 14:17:01 ubuntu CRON[5220]: pam_unix(cron:session): session opened for user root by (uid=0)
Dec 02 14:17:01 ubuntu CRON[5221]: (root) CMD (   cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.hourly)
Dec 02 14:17:01 ubuntu CRON[5220]: pam_unix(cron:session): session closed for user root
Dec 02 14:18:00 ubuntu systemd-timesyncd[1097]: Network configuration changed, trying to establish connection.
Dec 02 14:18:00 ubuntu systemd-timesyncd[1097]: Synchronized to time server 91.189.89.198:123 (ntp.ubuntu.com).
Dec 02 14:39:01 ubuntu CRON[5241]: pam_unix(cron:session): session opened for user root by (uid=0)
Dec 02 14:39:01 ubuntu CRON[5242]: (root) CMD (  [ -x /usr/lib/php/sessionclean ] && if [ ! -d /run/systemd/system ]; then /usr/lib/php/sessionclean; fi)
Dec 02 14:39:01 ubuntu CRON[5241]: pam_unix(cron:session): session closed for user root
Dec 02 14:39:44 ubuntu systemd[1]: Starting Clean php session files...
-- Subject: Unit phpsessionclean.service has begun start-up
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://www.ubuntu.com/support
--
-- Unit phpsessionclean.service has begun starting up.
Dec 02 14:39:44 ubuntu sessionclean[5244]: PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'mysqli' (tried: /usr/lib/php/20170718/mysqli (/usr/lib/php/2017071
Dec 02 14:39:44 ubuntu systemd[1]: Started Clean php session files.
-- Subject: Unit phpsessionclean.service has finished start-up
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://www.ubuntu.com/support
--
-- Unit phpsessionclean.service has finished starting up.
--
-- The start-up result is RESULT.
Dec 02 14:47:59 ubuntu systemd-timesyncd[1097]: Network configuration changed, trying to establish connection.
Dec 02 14:47:59 ubuntu systemd-timesyncd[1097]: Synchronized to time server 91.189.89.198:123 (ntp.ubuntu.com).
```

Comment: You'll find the answer in https://serverfault.com/questions/558283/apache2-config-variable-is-not-defined

Comment: I have gone through all the suggestions in the thread you provided and the thread that this is listed as a duplicate of and neither of them seem to have anything that is helping me. Could you maybe elaborate a bit on why you believe this issue answers my question and how I can apply the answers in the thread to my situation? Again, thank you very much for taking the time to look at my issue and apologies if this is something very obvious.

Comment: I have no idea what you actually did by *"going through all the suggestions in the thread"* but the problem is that an environment variable is not defined since you've restarted apache the wrong way. To cite *"This message is displayed __because you directly executed the apache2 binary__. In Ubuntu/Debian the apache config relies on the envvar file which is only activated.... "*. Solution is also there: *"...sudo service apache2 restart..."*.

Comment: Apologies for that, I should be more specific. Thank you for explaining the relation between the issues. When I run sudo service apache2 restart, I get the following result:

Warning: The unit file, source configuration file or drop-ins of apache2.service changed on disk. Run 'systemctl daemon-reload' to reload units.
Job for apache2.service failed because the control process exited with error code.
See "systemctl status apache2.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
So I run 'systemctl daemon-reload' successfully and try restart again. but I still get the job failed message.

Comment: running "systemctl status apache2.service" gives:
ubuntu systemd[1]: Starting The Apache HTTP Server...
ubuntu apachectl[4299]: AH00558: apache2: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using 192.168.178.24. Set the 'ServerNa
ubuntu apachectl[4299]: Action 'start' failed.
ubuntu apachectl[4299]: The Apache error log may have more information.
ubuntu systemd[1]: apache2.service: Control process exited, code=exited status=1
ubuntu systemd[1]: apache2.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
ubuntu systemd[1]: Failed to start The Apache HTTP Server.

Comment: From before, when I said I went through the thread, I tried Source my envvars: "source /etc/apache2/envvars" & "/usr/sbin/apache2 -V" which gave me the same result as mentioned in the solution. I then tried the suggested "sudo apache2ctl -S". And I tried the "sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 restart" which also gave the job failed result.

Comment: Can you verify that these environment variables are actually defined somewhere? Maybe you've just copied some config which uses these variables from somewhere else but this kind of config is actually the wrong one for your system? Obviously it fails to start since these environment variables are not defined.

Comment: My envvars file is located in /etc/apache2 and have the following line for APACHE_RUN_DIR:
export APACHE_RUN_DIR=/var/run/apache2$SUFFIX 
I persume this is correct, more or less all files in my apache instalation were put there by the apache instalation process. The only exception is the ssl folder located in /etc/apache2 which contains my .crt and .key

Comment: Then I don't know what's wrong with that either. I've reopened the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a lot of searching I found out that it was due to my key being corrupt.

I was able to determine this by checking the apache error log:

```
sudo nano /var/log/apache2/error.log

[Mon Dec 02 11:08:57.784521 2019] [ssl:error] [pid 4560] AH02579: Init: Private key not found
[Mon Dec 02 11:08:57.784840 2019] [ssl:error] [pid 4560] SSL Library Error: error:0D0680A8:asn1 encoding routines:asn1_check_tlen:wrong tag
[Mon Dec 02 11:08:57.784922 2019] [ssl:error] [pid 4560] SSL Library Error: error:0D08303A:asn1 encoding routines:asn1_template_noexp_d2i:nested asn1 error
[Mon Dec 02 11:08:57.784990 2019] [ssl:error] [pid 4560] SSL Library Error: error:0D0680A8:asn1 encoding routines:asn1_check_tlen:wrong tag
[Mon Dec 02 11:08:57.785061 2019] [ssl:error] [pid 4560] SSL Library Error: error:0D07803A:asn1 encoding routines:asn1_item_embed_d2i:nested asn1 error (Type=RSAPrivat$
[Mon Dec 02 11:08:57.785135 2019] [ssl:error] [pid 4560] SSL Library Error: error:04093004:rsa routines:old_rsa_priv_decode:RSA lib
[Mon Dec 02 11:08:57.785200 2019] [ssl:error] [pid 4560] SSL Library Error: error:0D0680A8:asn1 encoding routines:asn1_check_tlen:wrong tag
[Mon Dec 02 11:08:57.785269 2019] [ssl:error] [pid 4560] SSL Library Error: error:0D07803A:asn1 encoding routines:asn1_item_embed_d2i:nested asn1 error (Type=PKCS8_PRI$
[Mon Dec 02 11:08:57.785434 2019] [ssl:emerg] [pid 4560] AH02311: Fatal error initialising mod_ssl, exiting. See /var/log/apache2/error.log for more information
[Mon Dec 02 11:08:57.785469 2019] [ssl:emerg] [pid 4560] AH02564: Failed to configure encrypted (?) private key MyWebSite.com:443:0, check /etc/apache2/ssl/MyWebSite$
AH00016: Configuration Failed
```

As displayed, "Private key not found" was not referring to the path of the key, but rather the key being corrupt. I checked this by opening the key with:

```
sudo nano MyWebSite.key
```

If the key is correct, it will have the text

> ----- BEGIN PRIVATE KEY -----

at the top of the key. The solution was then to regenerate the certificate request, have the certificate re-issued and install the new certificate. I hope this helps you if you're in the same situation as I was.